# Composer dependencies in local package

Tags: composer-php

I use a local repository ("depA") within my projects composer.json:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "marc/depA",
            "version": "dev-master",
            "source": {
                "url": "/Users/Marc/Sites/depA",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "develop"
            }
        }
    }
],
"require": {
    "marc/depA": "dev-master",
```

This works like a charm but it won't resolve dependencies from "depA". This means since "depA" requires "depB" (in composer.json of "depA") -> "depB" wont be installed. 
Is this even possible with local packages?

Thanks,
Marc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining the package inline so if you do it like this you must redefine all the requires etc inline as well. That's really not the best way to go at it. If it's a git repo and it has a composer.json you'd better use a vcs repository e.g.:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "/Users/Marc/Sites/depA"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "marc/depA": "dev-master",
    }
}
```